# Weighted least square matrices dimensions

Tags: python

I want to perform the following Weighted least square operation:

```
L = ((x^t * W * x)^-1)(X^t *W*y)
Where x is(240, 60) matrix
y is (240, 1) matrix
W is diagonal matrix of shape (60, 60)
```

I tried to implement the first part before calculation the inverse x^t * W * x as following:

```
np.dot(x.transpose(),W,x)
```

i got the error:

```
 shapes (60,240) and (60,240) not aligned: 240 (dim 1) != 60 (dim 0)
```

Also implementing

```
 numpy.transpose(x)*W*y
```

gives the error

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (60,240) (240,1)
```

What would be the best way to complete the multiplication ?
I want then to implements the SVD method to get the inverse of the term (x^t * W * x)

Comment: `np.dot(x.transpose(), W, x)` is wrong because you specify `x` as the `out` parameter of [`np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). It seems you wanted to do `x.T * W * x`.

Comment: Your equation is false. `x^t` has dimension `(60, 240)`, which you can't multiply with `W`, which has dimension `(60, 60)`. Maybe what you meant was `((X×W)^t×y)` instead of `(X^t×W×y)`.

Comment: @BlackBeans if W has the dimension (60, 240) will it work with x.T * W * x ?

Comment: The rule for multiplication is easy: if you have two matrices `A` and `B`, with shape `(a, b)` and `(c, d)`, then you can multiply them `A×B` only if `b=c`, and then `C:=A×B` has shape `(a, d)`. So, `x` has shape `(240, 60)`, `W` has shape `(60, 60)` and `x^t` `(60, 240)`. If you write only the shapes in the multiplication, you get `(60, 240) × (60, 60) × (240, 60)`, which does not work. What would work is `x × W × x^t`, with shape `(240, 60) × (60, 60) × (60, 240) = (240, 240)`.

Comment: @BlackBeans in my example i tried to do X * W  *  
numpy.transpose(X) but i got the error " operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (240,60) (60,240)" shall i perform different type of multiplication ?

Comment: @ely66 yes, be very careful. There are two "conflicting" notations. In Python, when you have two numpy arrays `a` and `b`, `a*b` is an element-wise product, which means `a` and `b` must have (up to simple transforms, such as adding an axe) the same shape. It does not have an equivalent mathematical notation, because this product behaves poorly with linear algebra. On the other hand, `a.dot(b)` in Python stands for `a × b` (this notation is non-standard), that is, the usual matrix product in maths. When you see an equation, unless told otherwise, you should always go for the dot/matrix product.

Comment: @BlackBeans Its clear now but in my example i still got an error when i tried numpy.dot( numpy.transpose(X),W,X) The error  " shapes (60,240) and (60,240) not aligned: 240 (dim 1) != 60 (dim 0)" How can  perform the multiplication for the three parameters

Comment: Yes, this is to be expected because `numpy.dot(X.T, W, X)` (`X.T` is the same as `numpy.transpose(X)`) is `x^t × W × x`, as explained before the shapes are `(60, 240) × (60, 60) × (240, 60)`, so it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as numpy

x = numpy.random.random((240, 60))
y = numpy.random.random((240, 1))
W = numpy.random.random((60, 60))

second_part = numpy.dot(numpy.transpose(numpy.dot(x,W)),y)
```